# How do I allow users to add my application to their pages through my website?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an application on my website and I want my users to be able to add this application to the fan pages they manage as a tab just by clicking on its icon on my website. I'm already able to connect the application to facebook, however when it get the authentication page it didn't give the window to choose to which page I want to add the app although I use page_manage in my permission request. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to ask for any permissions, you can simply use the [Add to Page tab dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/).